# How to display a var in string format?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

In the view, 

PAYMENT1 = 1,200.50

PAYMENT2 = 1,500.50

totalpayment = 2701

I want the totalpayment to have the format with comma.

totalpayment= 2,701.00

I tried using `.ToString` but didn't work. Any idea?

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, bool update = false)
{
    TBL_PROJ project = db.TBL_PROJ.Find(id);

    ViewBag.PAYMENT1 = Convert.ToDecimal(project.PAYMENT1).ToString("#,##0.00");
    ViewBag.PAYMENT2 = Convert.ToDecimal(project.PAYMENT2).ToString("#,##0.00");

    var  totalPayment = project.PAYMENT1 + project.PAYMENT2;
    project.TotalPayment = (float)Math.Round(totalPayment, 2); //This Part

    return View(project);
}
```

Comment: var won't be apply on string , you need to use convert.tostring() and after that apply format on that string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whereever you are displaying totalpayment use string.Format(format, totalpayment) or totalpayment.ToString(format);

As I expect totalPayment would become of type decimal and project.TotalPayment is also decimal type. Doing any formatting on totalpayment and storing it in project.TotalPayment makes no sense.

lets say you are displaying total payment in a label lblTotalPayment. You should do something like:

```
lblTotalPayment.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", project.TotalPayment);
```

or

```
lblTotalPayment.Text = project.TotalPayment.ToString("#,##0.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply format in last statement

```
project.TotalPayment = (float)Math.Round(totalPayment, 2).ToString("#,##0.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var aa= 1200.60;
        var bb = 1245.50;
        var pay = Math.Round((aa + bb),2).ToString("#,##0.00");
 Console.WriteLine(pay);
result will be "2,446.10"
```

> You have to apply format like that, hope it will help for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not dealing with "var", but an actual type (probably `decimal` or `double`), only that the type is implicitly defined (also inferred type). [An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

So what you are actually trying to do, is find a way how to display a `float` with formatting.

Since `project.TotalPayment` is a `float` and for quickly get it working, you could put it in a `ViewBag`, convert it to `string` with formatting and use it in your view template, as you do with the other two properties.

```
ViewBag.TotalPayment = Convert.ToDecimal(totalPayment).ToString("#,##0.00");
```

However, from the code I see I can expect that this is a generated property from your ORM and therefore your problem is that you can not modify your `TBL_PROJ class`. This is where the view model comes into the game and for your case could be defined like so:

```
public class EditPaymentViewModel 
{ 
    public EditPaymentViewModel(decimal p1, decimal p2)
    {
        this.Payment1 = p1;
        this.Payment2 = p2;
    }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}")]
    public decimal Payment1  { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}")]
    public decimal Payment2  { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}")]
    public decimal TotalPayment  { get { return Payment1+Payment2; } }
}
```

Then your action method would look like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, bool update = false)
{
    TBL_PROJ project = db.TBL_PROJ.Find(id);

    var viewModel = new EditPaymentViewModel(project.Payment1, project.Payment2); 

    return View(project);
}
```

Of course, you would have to change your view to accept the model of type `EditPaymentViewModel` (`@model EditPaymentViewModel`). 
You can read more about `DisplayFormatAttribute` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).